# How to Find the Name of a Project with Most Employee

Tags: mysql

How should i find the name of the project with the most employees assigned to it?

```
projectTable
------------
Pid
Pname
Budget
ManagerId

EmployeeTable
-------------
Eid
ename
city
status
age

WorksTable
----------
pid
eid
w_hour
```

Comment: Without far more detail on the schema of your database, there is no way for any member of the public at large to answer this question.

Comment: @Hunter, that makes it a lot more readable. Nice.

Comment: there appears to be enough information, @JamesMcLeod, but it's missing any attempt to solve it, which makes it look like a homework problem.

Comment: well it is a lab exercise.and my head is on fire.

Comment: Post-update, yes. The initial version, not so much. Much better after the update.

Comment: Kindly place into your question sample data for each table and the result you desire so we can easily answer your question. Thanks.

Comment: employeeTable( E1 , Ester, london , senior , 52);

Comment: worksTable ( E1, P1, 5)

Comment: projectTable( P1 , Newbenefits , 1, m-5)

Answer (score 0):

You need to do a count of employees by project. That can be done in WorksTable (assuming 1:1) and involves COUNT() and group by.  The groups are by project.  If you group by employee id by mistake, then instead you will see how many projects each employee is assigned to (mostly small numbers).

You also need to look up the Pname for the pid, from projectTable.  Combining those into one query should look like this:

`SELECT t1.pid, count(t1.eid) as employeeCount, t2.Pname from WorksTable as t1, projectTable as t2 where t1.pid=t2.Pid group by t1.pid;`